Which model should I use to extract NER entities from social media bios of various users?
I want to extract entities such as Organization(companies,brands,etc), Religion, Occupations, Nationality and hobbies. I will be working with millions of data and spacy is not very efficient. I have tried fine tuning BERT for NER, but it is missing out on a lot of important entities in my data. I have given it a training data of about 1,000,000 rows. Any suggestions or tips on the best way to approach this?

Since you mentioned that you have training dataset also, then you can try several approaches like

You should try newer LLMs like llama3, GPT or Claude
If they are expensive then train a smaller LM like T5, or llama3-8B model  to give the NER values as structured JSON output.

Here The output label will be JSON, example
 {"Organization": "xxx", "Religion" : "xxx", "Occupations" : "xxx", "Nationality" : "xxx", "hobbies": "xxx"}

Edit:
I have used BERT/T5/LLMs for NER extraction.
LLM > T5 >> BERT models

T5 and llama3 8b are more suited to text classification. Not sure how they will perform for NER. I was wondering if some non contextual models would be a good idea like KNN classification.

No, they are generalized models and can adapt these tasks easily
